# Notes disappeared from iPhone

Tags: iphone, backup, notes.app

All notes have disappeared from my iphone and cannot be found on my computer or iCloud. Why am I backing up my computer? Are they hidden somewhere? They aren't in Mail, either.

Comment: If you are certain that you were using iCloud for Notes, are they visible in the iCloud.com website?

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you using? In newer versions notes has moved from mail to its own application "Notes". Though I don't know how they disappeared.